# Mock an interface using PowerMockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermock

I need to mock a method in hbase apis. Please find the method below

```
 public static Connection createConnection() throws IOException {
    return createConnection(HBaseConfiguration.create(), null, null);
 }
```

Please find the source code for Connection interface in the below link

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.hbase/hbase-client/1.1.1/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Connection.java

I have tried as below

```
Connection mockconnection = PowerMockito.mock(Connection.class);
PowerMockito.when(ConnectionFactory.createConnection()).thenReturn(mockconnection);
```

Is this correct form of mocking as it is not working properly

Comment: Have you added @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) and @PrepareForTest(ConnectionFactory.class) to the top of the test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### To mock a `static` method you need to:

1. Add `@PrepareForTest` at class or method level.

*Example:*

```
@PrepareForTest(Static.class) // Static.class contains static methods
```

2. `Call PowerMockito.mockStatic(class)` to mock a static class (use `PowerMockito.spy(class)` to mock a specific method):

*Example:*

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(Static.class);
```

3. Just use `Mockito.when()` to setup your expectation:

*Example:*

```
Mockito.when(Static.firstStaticMethod(param)).thenReturn(value);
```

---

**So in your case, It would be something like that:**

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class ConnectionFactoryTest {

    @Test
    @PrepareForTest(ConnectionFactory.class)
    public void testConnection() throws IOException {
        Connection mockconnection = PowerMockito.mock(Connection.class);
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(ConnectionFactory.class);
        PowerMockito.when(ConnectionFactory.createConnection()).thenReturn(mockconnection);

        // Do something here
    }
}
```

More details about [**how to mock a static method**](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/mockitousage#mocking-static-method)

Comment: Hi @Nicolas Filotto I have edited my question and I have some query which i have mentioned after new edit.

Comment: please create a new question for it

Comment: Hi @Nicolas Filotto Please find the question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41165788/mocking-a-method-returns-null

Comment: @Reddevil perfect, I need to go now, I will answer asap if you don't have any answer before I return

Comment: No I dont have any questions