# Mocking a method returns null

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermock

I have the following method

```
public ResultScanner getScanner(Scan scan) {
    Table table = getTableInstance("Sampletable");
    return table.getScanner(scan);
}
```

For this I have written following junit test code

```
Connection mockconnection = PowerMockito.mock(Connection.class);
Table mocktable = PowerMockito.mock(Table.class);
PowerMockito.when(mockconnection.getTable(TableName.valueOf(Mockito.anyString())))
    .thenReturn(mocktable);

Scan mockedScan = PowerMockito.mock(Scan.class);
ResultScanner mockrs = PowerMockito.mock(ResultScanner.class);
PowerMockito.when(mocktable.getScanner(mockedScan)).thenReturn(mockrs);
```

while testing the method

the statement

```
Table table = getTableInstance("Sampletable");
```

runs fine and gives the mocked table object but the statement

```
table.getScanner(scan);
```

returns null.

Please find the source code for Table interface in the below link

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.hbase/hbase-client/1.1.1/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Table.java

Please guide me in this??

Comment: Add full code containing your unit test

Comment: where's the `scan` coming from in your method?

Comment: sorry i have missed the argument

Comment: Please show the method `getTableInstance()`

Comment: please also provide your entire test code

Comment: Just for the record: you absolutely do **not** need Powermock for this. And the simply rule should be: only only only turn to the Powermock.... side of things ... if you absolutely have no other choice.

Answer (score 2):

Replace last line of test case with

```
 PowerMockito.when(mocktable.getScanner(Mockito.any(Scan.class))).thenReturn(mockrs);
```

It should work

Comment: And replace `Mockito.any(Scan.class)` with `Mockito.eq(mockedScan)`. OP already know the used `Scan` instance, so he could also use that to check if the "correct" one has been used, instead of a new one created in `getScanner` (which would be an coding issue and should result in a test failure).